# Changing transaction validation process in Ethereum

Tags: mining, security, vulnerability

I am doing a research about Ethereum smart contracts security. For this purpose I want to make some changes in Ethereum miner and transactions validation process (editing miner for automatically reverting malicious transactions).
I should choose a miner to change its source code. Please introduce me some good open source miners for this research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Miners only calculate a block's proof of work, they do not execute or validate transactions.

Ethereum clients like [geth](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum), [openethereum](https://github.com/openethereum/openethereum) will validate and execute transactions.

Comment: Thanks, Which Ethereum client is less complicated for editing its source code?

Comment: @MortezaAmirmohseni I won't say one is better than other. If you are familiar with go language I'd recommend starting with geth. If you like rust more start with openethereum. There are several [implementations](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Clients,-tools,-dapp-browsers,-wallets-and-other-projects), but geth an openethereum (former parity) are production ready.